# Is Jenkins-X and Jenkins Helm chart same?

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-x

I was working on Jenkins for many days and deploy my services to Kubernetes.

I recently came across Jenkins X, I also found a Helm chart for Jenkins through which I can host Jenkins in Kubernetes. Now I'm confused if they both are same?

Answer (score 7):

No they are different. I assume the helm chart you found installs and configure Jenkins on Kubernetes - perhaps configured with some agents to run builds.

Jenkins X is a kubernetes native implementation of CI/CD, it uses some components of Jenkins, but has a lot more to it (for example, applications, environments, review apps, deployments and so on) for running apps ON kubernetes in a CI/CD fashion. The Jenkins helm chart likely sets up a single server.

edit: in the time since, Jenkins X has evolved a lot. It is now build using he Tekton engine for pipeline by default, and has many moving parts, so is quite different from running a more classic like Jenkins master/agent setup in a Kubernetes cluster.

Comment: For reference this is the Jenkins Helm chart mentioned - https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/jenkins